# Creating Multiple Buttons Using React Classes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, firebase

I'm currently trying to return multiple buttons from a class using Reactjs.  Currently I can get all the buttons to return but the `onClick` function will only work on the last button to be displayed.  If anyone can help its greatly appreciated.  Here are the important lines of code.

```
          let GroupCollection2 = db.collection('groups');
            GroupCollection2.get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        if(doc.get('ModuleCode') === document.getElementById("groupSearch").value)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("groupDisplayError").innerHTML = "";
                            if(found === false){
                                document.getElementById("groupDisplayTable").innerHTML = '<tr id="groupDisplayTableHeader"><th>Group Name</th><th>Module Code</th><th>Join Or View Group</th></tr>';
                            }
                            found = true;
                            document.getElementById("groupDisplayTable").innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+doc.id+"</td><td>"+doc.data().ModuleCode+"</td><td class='groupDisplayTableButton'></td></tr>";
                            ReactDOM.render(<Button command={doc.id} />, document.getElementsByClassName('groupDisplayTableButton')[count]);
                            count++;
                        }
                    });
                    if(found === false){
                        document.getElementById("groupDisplayError").innerHTML = "No Results.";
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                });
```

and

```
class Button extends React.Component{

    joinGroup(command){
        alert(command);
    }

    render(){
        return(<button onClick={this.joinGroup.bind(this, this.props.command ) }>Join Group</button>);
    }


}
```

The entire code is here:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { compose } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signout } from "../store/actions/auth";
import requireAuth from "./hoc/requireAuth";
import firebase from "../services/firebase.js";

import Calendar from "./Planner.js"
//<Calendar />
var db = firebase.firestore();

const Main = ({ signout }) => {
  return (
    <div id="homePage" className="container">


      <div className="row">
        <div class="col s6" id="createPage">
              <form id="createGroup">
            <i className="large material-icons prefix search-icon">group_add</i>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col s12">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s12 vert-align">
                          <input type="text" id="cgroupName" name="groupName"/>
                    <label htmlFor="cgroupName">Group Name</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s12 vert-align">
                    <input type="text" id="cgroupModuleCode" name="moduleCode"/>
                    <label htmlFor="cgroupModuleCode">Module Code</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <input type="button" value="Create Group" onClick={ ()=> createGroup()}/>
                </div>
                <p id="groupCreateError"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
              </form>
          </div>

        <div className="col s6">
          {/*<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>*/}
          {/* Renders the search bar */}
          <i className="large material-icons prefix search-icon">group</i>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="input-field col s12 vert-align">
                  <i className="material-icons prefix search-icon">search</i>
                  <input type= "text" id ="groupSearch" name="searchGroup"/>
                  <label htmlFor="groupSearch">Search For A Group</label>
                  <a className="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat search-btn" onClick={ ()=> searchGroups()}>Search</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* Display any searched groups here */}
          <div class="row" id="groupDisplay">
            <p id="groupDisplayError"></p>
            <table id="groupDisplayTable">
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={ () => profile()} hidden>Profile</button>
      <button className="btn-switch" onClick={() => signout()}>Log Out</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.firebaseReducer.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    signout: () => dispatch(signout())
  };
}

function profile(){

}

function logOut(){
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.display = "none";
  signout();
}

function searchGroups(){
    if(document.getElementById("groupSearch").value === ""){
        document.getElementById("groupDisplayError").innerHTML = "Please enter a value and try again.";
    }
    else{
        var found = false;
        var count = 0;
        let GroupCollection = db.collection('groups').doc(document.getElementById("groupSearch").value);
        GroupCollection.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                found = true;
                document.getElementById("groupDisplayError").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("groupDisplayTable").innerHTML = '<tr id="groupDisplayTableHeader"><th>Group Name</th><th>Module Code</th><th>Join Or View Group</th></tr>';
                document.getElementById("groupDisplayTable").innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+doc.id+"</td><td>"+doc.data().ModuleCode+"</td><td class='groupDisplayTableButton'></td></tr>";
                ReactDOM.render(<Button command={doc.id}/>, document.getElementsByClassName('groupDisplayTableButton')[count]);
                count++;
            } 
          })
          .catch(err => {
            document.getElementById("groupDisplayError").innerHTML = "Error getting document: "+err;
          });

          let GroupCollection2 = db.collection('groups');
            GroupCollection2.get()
                .then(snapshot => {
                    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        if(doc.get('ModuleCode') === document.getElementById("groupSearch").value)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("groupDisplayError").innerHTML = "";
                            if(found === false){
                                document.getElementById("groupDisplayTable").innerHTML = '<tr id="groupDisplayTableHeader"><th>Group Name</th><th>Module Code</th><th>Join Or View Group</th></tr>';
                            }
                            found = true;
                            document.getElementById("groupDisplayTable").innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+doc.id+"</td><td>"+doc.data().ModuleCode+"</td><td class='groupDisplayTableButton'></td></tr>";
                            ReactDOM.render(<Button command={doc.id} />, document.getElementsByClassName('groupDisplayTableButton')[count]);
                            count++;
                        }
                    });
                    if(found === false){
                        document.getElementById("groupDisplayError").innerHTML = "No Results.";
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                });

    }
}

function createGroup(){
        let GroupCollection = db.collection('groups').doc(document.getElementById("cgroupName").value);
        GroupCollection.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                document.getElementById("groupCreateError").innerHTML = "Group created sucessfully.";

                const GroupCollection2 = db.collection('groups');
                GroupCollection2.doc(document.getElementById("cgroupName").value).set({
                ModuleCode:document.getElementById("cgroupModuleCode").value,
                Timetable: "",
                User0: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
                User1: "",
                User2: "",
                User3: "",
                User4: "",
                User5: "",
                User6: "",
                User7: "",
                User8: "",
                User9: "",
                })
            } else {
                document.getElementById("groupCreateError").innerHTML = "Group Name Already Exists.";
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            document.getElementById("groupCreateError").innerHTML = "Error getting document: "+err;
          });
}

class Button extends React.Component{

    joinGroup(command){
        alert(command);
    }

    render(){
        return(<button onClick={this.joinGroup.bind(this, this.props.command ) }>Join Group</button>);
    }


}

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  ),
  requireAuth
)(Main);
```

Comment: If you are using React why are you setting .innerHTML on the DOM? Is that deliberate or have you just started using React?

Comment: This was the first time I was using React and I understand that you aren't meant to set innerHTML on the DOM now but at the start I didn't.  Its too late though to go back and change everything now.

Comment: So what happens when you click on the other buttons? Does it throw an error? Can you log stuff to the console? What happens?

Comment: Definitely consider taking the time to refactor if you find yourself asking more questions in the future, it will be much easier to help you if your code is less cryptic.

Comment: If I click on the other buttons absolutely nothing happens.  I can't console log things not anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to make sure each button as a unique key. In this case, using the doc.id may work. So, you would want to add a key prop as below:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Button command={doc.id} key={doc.id} />,
   document.getElementsByClassName('groupDisplayTableButton')[count]);
```

If there's any chance that you will have multiple of the same doc.id, you could modify the key to include the count to ensure each button has a unique key. i.e key={doc.id + count}

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried both methods but only the last button is still running its onClick method.  Is there maybe anything I have to do in the Button class using the key?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are binding the joinGroup function properly. Try replacing your Button class with the following functional component:

```
const Button = ({ command }) => {
  const joinGroup = _command => alert(_command);

  return (
    <button type="button" key={command} onClick={() => joinGroup(command)}>
      Join Group
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Replacing the class with this functions produces the same output where only the last button works.  I'm starting to think it might be a problem with the `ReactDOM.render(<Button command={doc.id} />, document.getElementsByClassName('groupDisplayTableButton')[count]);` line.

Comment: Yeah, this hybrid approach to writing react and interacting with the DOM is horrible. I'm so used to thinking in react now that I don't even know where to begin. there is also very little incentive to answer this question, as I doubt anyone would want to encourage this approach. I definitely recommend refactoring. If you can get a code sandbox up with your code, I'm happy to spend some time refactoring it so that it does things the react way.

Comment: I'm very confused about using reactDOM.render in the middle of an app. I'm certain this is the problem here. You should render your buttons into their parent component. You should only use reactDOM to render your main component to the HTML file. If you want to render to multiple places in your HTML file then use react portals.

Comment: Yeah I know my approach is terrible, thank you for offering the time to refactor my code but its a project and I would prefer to hand up my own code even as bad as it is.  I'll try using react portals to fix my problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have a solution. That said, I definitely think this line is the problem: `ReactDOM.render(<Button command={doc.id} />, document.getElementsByClassName('groupDisplayTableButton')[count]);`.

Do not use `ReactDOM.render` inside the app, render the buttons to their parent, in this case, the table. You can't exactly do that since the table doesn't exist because you are manually adding elements to the DOM.

In the process of trying to figure out what is going on, I ended up refactoring half your code. Thought I'd share it in case it helps at some point.

[Here is a sandbox to show that the click handler works with multiple table buttons](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-babbage-92vik).

I removed the search function and mocked out firebase.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return <Main />;
}

const Main = () => {

  // fake firebase mock
  const [firebaseMock, setFirebaseMock] = useState("");

  // input fields
  const [groupName, setGroupName] = useState("");
  const [moduleCode, setModuleCode] = useState("");

  // error messages
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const createGroup = (_groupName, _moduleCode) => {
    // ensure user submist a group name and a module code
    if (!_groupName || !_moduleCode) {
      setErrorMessage("You must provide a group name and a module code.");
      return;
    }

    // if group already exists with the same name, create an error message
    if (Object.keys(firebaseMock).includes(_groupName)) {
      setErrorMessage("Group Name Already Exists.");
      return;
    }

    setFirebaseMock({
      ...firebaseMock,
      [_groupName]: { ModuleCode: _moduleCode }
    });

    // clear inputs
    setGroupName("");
    setModuleCode("");
  };

  return (
    <div id="homePage" className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div class="col s6" id="createPage">
          <form id="createGroup">
            <i className="large material-icons prefix search-icon">group_add</i>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col s12">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s12 vert-align">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="cgroupName"
                      name="groupName"
                      value={groupName}
                      onChange={e => setGroupName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="cgroupName">Group Name</label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s12 vert-align">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      id="cgroupModuleCode"
                      name="moduleCode"
                      value={moduleCode}
                      onChange={e => setModuleCode(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="cgroupModuleCode">Module Code</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <input
                    type="button"
                    value="Create Group"
                    onClick={() => createGroup(groupName, moduleCode)}
                  />
                </div>
                <p id="groupCreateError">{errorMessage}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="groupDisplay">
          {!!Object.keys(firebaseMock).length && (
            <table id="groupDisplayTable">
              <thead>
                <tr id="groupDisplayTableHeader">
                  <th>Group Name</th>
                  <th>Module Code</th>
                  <th>Join Or View Group</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {Object.keys(firebaseMock).map(groupId => (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{groupId}</td>
                    <td>{firebaseMock[groupId].ModuleCode}</td>
                    <td class="groupDisplayTableButton">
                      <Button command={groupId} />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Button = ({ command }) => {
  const joinGroup = _command => console.log(_command);

  return (
    <button type="button" key={command} onClick={() => joinGroup(command)}>
      Join Group
    </button>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The only difference here is that none of my functions contains HTML, they just manipulate state. In the future, a simple way to think in react is to always make sure that HTML code only lives in the render function. That way everything else only manipulates data and state. This decoupling of the soul of an app (data) from the body of app (HTML)lets the HTML 'react' to changes in state, which is the whole point of the framework.